# Looking for video courses on competition math

Tags: soft-question

I’m looking for good video lectures on these subjects:

Combinatorics

Geometry (past high school level)

Algebra (again past high school level)

Number Theory

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

MIT has free on advanced mathematics courses that can be found free of charge. They are the ones there students take and are very rigorous

Comment: Unfortunately, MIT only offers videos for select courses, and the subjects I am looking for have none.